# Add Plaid UI into Xamarin Forms Cross platform mobile App (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, finance, plaid

I'm new to working with APIs and I'm trying to recreate the app Mint using Xamarin Forms. I want to integrate Plaid's UI into my app so the user can login to their bank from there and I can retrieve all the bank data associated with it but I'm lost on how to integrate it.

The idea is that when the user clicks on a button, this UI should pop up, allowing the user to login to their bank using their bank credentials. I also want to save the bank credentials so the user doesn't have to enter it each time they login.

This is what the UI looks like:

[image]

I'm also using the Acklann.Plaid NuGET Package for creating the access token.

Comment: You can use Plaid's `Link` to show their native UI on mobile devices, I personally do not know of existing 3rd party Xamarin binding libraries for their iOS/Android SDKs as they to not directly support Xamarin (I created them for a client a while back). Note: You will NOT have access to the user's bank credentials, only a `Link` token is returned which you then exchange for an access token via their rest endpoints (i.e. Plaid.NET wraps that process). That OAuth2 token can be stored for reuse and refreshing.

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure what exactly the question being asked is, can you clarify that if you are still needing help?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate Plaid into my xamarin forms project by adding the Plaid UI and using their Auth, Balance, and Transaction products to get user data such as transaction info, and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to integrate the UI and use the Acklann.Plaid nuget package to create and store client and token info